# Grand Canyon Skywalk - details on access

Tags: car-rentals, grand-canyon, accessibility

So oddly, the [official site of the Grand Canyon Skywalk](http://www.grandcanyonskywalk.com/) (as far as I can tell) has nothing on it.  The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Canyon_Skywalk) has info on it, but there are a few issues:

- the access road is apparently unpaved
- the access road is considered 'off-road' which can be against rental agreements
- you may need to hire a shuttle?
- in February, the local tribe took over it, and are apparently still running it.

**I am struggling to find information on a) whether it's running as normal, b) what the deal with the access road is, and c) costs. Anyone?**

Comment: The official site is http://www.grandcanyonwest.com/

Comment: Don't support those scum.  They basically stole it from the developer and now are claiming sovereign immunity when the arbiter ruled against them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was in the 'neighbourhood' of it last year. It's run by the Hualapai Nation, and still runs as normal.

- 9 miles of the 21 'country road' miles are unpaved. They say it's 2.5 hours from Las Vegas. I'd say it's more like 3.5 hours (and got that confirmed in Peach Springs), and if you want to do it on your way to/from the Grand Canyon, count on another 3.5 hours back to Seligman.
- Prices are quite stiff:

  - It seems that the cheapest rate is the Hualapai Legacy package ($44) + Skywalk entry ($30) = $74 (with taxes) to get there (+ your gas),
  - They [advertise](http://www.grandcanyonwest.com/adventure.php) for the package that includes the Skywalk at $88 / person.
- You have to park before the canyon and take the shuttle (included in your ticket).
- Opening hours from their FAQ:

  - Grand Canyon West is open from 8am to 5pm daily from October to March. We are open from 7am to 7pm daily from April to September. We are open every day of the year including all major holidays.
  - Last ticket is sold **one and a half hours** prior to closing time.
  - Note: **Arizona does not participate in Daylight Savings Time**, so there is a 1 hour difference from Las Vegas and California (Pacific Standard Time) when Daylight Savings time is inactive. When daylight savings time is active, the time is the same as Pacific Standard Time.

This is truly a full-day thing IMO.